# Add scrollbar to a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with thead.

```
 <table style="width: 100%; height: 420px; min-width: 500px" class="table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>امکانات</th>
        <th>قیمت </th>
        <th>موجود </th>
        <th>اطلاعات بیشتر</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var product in Model.AllProduct)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Title</td>
            <td class="text-center">@product.Price.ToString("##,###")</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @product.IsValid
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @product.Description
            </td>

        </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

I want to add scrollbar to this table .

I add this style.

```
 <style>
    tbody {
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        display: block;
    }

    thead > tr {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;
    }
</style>
```

It is add scroll to table but width of `th` don't set to column.

When i remove this style `th` size is ok .

http://jsfiddle.net/ArGorgin/rc2xkfrw/

[image]

Comment: Can you add a http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ArGorgin/rc2xkfrw/

Comment: to make the `tbody` scrollable while the `thead` stays static with CSS alone is a bit complicated, but doable. Not really an "answer" but view source on this page, and you should be able to sort it out: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to  Fixed size for column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this script for set size for th

```
  var $table = $('table.scroll'),
  $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
  colWidth;

    // Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
    $(window).resize(function () {
        // Get the tbody columns width array
        colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function () {
            return $(this).width();
        }).get();

        // Set the width of thead columns
        $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function (i, v) {
            $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
        });

        // Set the width of thead columns
        $table.find('tfoot tr').children().each(function (i, v) {
            $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
        });
    }).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

and set style

```
  table.scroll tbody,
    table.scroll thead, table.scroll tfoot {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create div element around the table and define its height and set `overflow: auto;` to it. Then the table will be scrollable and header columns are in the same position as contents. This solutions has minor issue because when you scroll down the headers will scroll too and user is not able to see them without scrollin back to up.

Comment: Thanks ,but i want scroll tbody no thead.

Answer (score 0):

```
th{
width:200px;
}
td{
width:200px;    
}
```

You can define a specific width for th and td and make them equal therefore they will be aligned right and content will be scrollable.

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rc2xkfrw/1/

Comment: Thanks, but  my column's width is auto(set with content)

Answer (score 0):

U can do this in this way.
            #scrol{

```
            width: 408px;
            max-height: 88px;
            overflow-y: scroll
        }
```

and u may change the max-height according to ur requirements.